# Increasing acceleration of model on keypress?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I'm attempting to rotate a single cube in an open space. At first, it starts off stationary, and then on key press it should increase rotation speed in a specific access on a specific key press.

My initial code looked like this:

```
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.x * glfwGetTime()), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.y * glfwGetTime())), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.z * glfwGetTime())), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
```

On a general keypress, say A, the code would look like such:

```
if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS){
    rotationAngle.x += 0.01;
}
```

This would increase rotation speed, but since `glfwGetTime()` is constantly increasing, when I hold down the key it would spin very quickly and then when the key is unpressed, it returns to the normal rotation speed.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use delta-time (the change in time since the last frame) instead of time. I'm not sure if GLFW has a specific function for it but you could do it like so:

```
time = glfwGetTime();
delta = time - lastTime;

// do stuff with delta ...

lastTime = time;
```

Comment: That's what I thought too at some point. I tried using the rotationAngle * deltaTime, and it does rotate on keypress but then it starts glitching out when unpressed.

Comment: Are you resetting your rotation values to 0 when the key is not pressed?

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I picture the code is something like this

```
while(condition)
{
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.x * glfwGetTime()), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.y * glfwGetTime())), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.z * glfwGetTime())), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        rotationAngle.x += 0.01;
    }
}
```

When you hold down the key, the rotationAngle increases by 0.01 each time and each time the loop iterates, the rotate function rotates by a larger amount every loop. To prevent that from happening, the if statement should only activate when going from "unpressed" to "pressed". We can do this with a flag.

```
while(condition)
{
    static bool keyDown = false;

    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.x * glfwGetTime()), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.y * glfwGetTime())), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle.z * glfwGetTime())), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        // We don't combine !keyDown in the outer if statement because
        // we don't want the else statement to be activated whenever either 
        // statement is false.

        // If key was not previously pressed, then activate. Otherwise, 
        // key is already down and we ignore this.
        if(!keyDown)
        {
            rotationAngle.x += 0.01;
            keyDown = true;
        }
    }
    // Once you let go of the key, this part activates and resets the flag 
    // as well as the rotation angle.
    else
    {
        rotationAngle.x = 0.0;
        keydown = false;
    }
}
```

It should look more or less like this. I don't know the specifics of glfwGetKey so you might need to have some more conditions to check for the state of the key.